# How to implement single sign on (SSO) as an identity provider & service provider

Tags: single-sign-on, service-provider

Please help. I'm aware there are several posts / docs about SSO implementations but I still can't seem to find one that addresses my use case - probably because I'm still new to SSO implementation.

**Scenario:**
I have an existing Symfony 4 application with existing users. I want so that when users log into the app, they are automatically signed into Outlook Office 365 (web). Exactly the same implementations on https://mysso.centennialcollege.ca/. Please NOTE I do not want office 365 to authorize my app using the code flow approach, rather I want office 365 to recognize users signed into my app as valid identities.

Has anyone implemented this or has ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. You're likely going to need to change the existing application in some manner in order to achieve true single sign-on. You'll need to ensure that authentication against the Symphony app leads to the presence of a session that can be used to trigger subsequent sessions in a SSO framework supported by O365.

In your case, I'd take a look at SAML and, more specifically, [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org).

Are you affiliated with the organization you linked to in some way? Because just by looking at the login page that looks like they've already got some sort of SAML Identity Provider solution... you can just integrate your Symphony app with that IdP in that case, and correlate the principal returned to your SP application from the SAML assertion on successful authentication against the user data in your existing DB. You wouldn't *have* to use SSP in that case... any kind of SAML middleware would work.

Comment: Thanks for you response @Kellen Murphy.

Yes, I've read SAML and SimpleSAMLphp, and have configured simplesamlphp (specifically as Identity provider) to produce the code and metadata necessary.

On symfony side, I've implemented and configured lightsaml/sp-bundle package. I still have to setup the login page to link with SSO auth - I'm not sure about this part but I intended to play around with until I figure it out. 

And, no I'm not affiliated with the organisation I posted. That was just an example as their SSO works exactly the way I want mine to work.